# matching complex strings names in data frame using R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, string-matching, grepl

I have two data frames:

```
name1 name2
AaI08 BbZ09
AaB65 BbX02
```

and a second one with the code (omitting the initial Aa or Bb)which contains the description:

```
Code meaning
I08  Volvo
B65  Seat
Z093 BMW
X021 Fiat
```

I would like to match the first two numbers after the letter from the second data frame and bring it to the first data frame. The ultimate result should look something like this:

```
name1 name2
Volvo BMW
Seat  Fiat
```

my intuition is to use the function `grepl` and `str_extract(code, '[A-Z]\\d{2}')` to match and gather the first two numbers after the letter respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove first two characters from the string and then perform the join.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(Code = sub('..', '', name1)) %>%
  #If you want to remove initial Aa or Bb
  #mutate(Code = sub('^(Aa|Bb)', '', name1)) %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = 'Code')

#  Code name1 name2 meaning
#1  B65 AaB65 BbX02    Seat
#2  I08 AaI08 BbZ09   Volvo
```

In  base R :

```
merge(transform(df1, Code = sub('..', '', name1)), df2, by = 'Code')
```

Comment: Your base-R solution needs to be hyped. Looks simple but is very elegant. Maybe a small explanation on what it's doing for those who find this later?

Comment: Actually base R answer is doing nothing different than the `dplyr` answer. It removes first 2 characters from `name1` and joins the two dataframe based on the common part available in both the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
sapply(d1, function(x) d2$meaning[match(substr(x,4,5),substr(d2$Code,2,3))]) %>% as.data.frame()
  name1 name2
1 Volvo   BMW
2  Seat  Fiat
```

Data used:

```
d1
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name1 name2
  <chr> <chr>
1 AaI08 BbZ09
2 AaB65 BbX02
d2
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Code  meaning
  <chr> <chr>  
1 I08   Volvo  
2 B65   Seat   
3 Z093  BMW    
4 X021  Fiat
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsub` and regular expressions.

```
f <- function(x) gsub("\\D+?(\\d{2}).*", "\\1", x)
sapply(dat1, function(x) dat2$meaning[match(f(x), f(dat2$Code))])
#      name1   name2 
# [1,] "Volvo" "BMW" 
# [2,] "Seat"  "Fiat"
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat1 <- structure(list(name1 = c("AaI08", "AaB65"), name2 = c("BbZ09", 
"BbX02")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

dat2 <- structure(list(Code = c("I08", "B65", "Z093", "X021"), meaning = c("Volvo", 
"Seat", "BMW", "Fiat")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```